# Have git diff color customization

Tags: git, colors, diff

How can `git diff` color be changed to one's disposal, or such as for `diff` ...?

in ~/.gitconfig:

```
[color "diff"]
  added = yellow
  changed = red bold
```

not work.
Please sincere help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git-config(1)` manual details the available slots; your `added` and `changed` might work instead as `new` and `old`.

```
   color.diff.<slot>
       Use customized color for diff colorization.  <slot> specifies which
       part of the patch to use the specified color, and is one of context
       (context text - plain is a historical synonym), meta
       (metainformation), frag (hunk header), func (function in hunk
       header), old (removed lines), new (added lines), commit (commit
       headers), whitespace (highlighting whitespace errors), oldMoved
       (deleted lines), newMoved (added lines), oldMovedDimmed,
       oldMovedAlternative, oldMovedAlternativeDimmed, newMovedDimmed,
       newMovedAlternative newMovedAlternativeDimmed (See the <mode>
       setting of --color-moved in git-diff(1) for details),
       contextDimmed, oldDimmed, newDimmed, contextBold, oldBold, and
       newBold (see git-range-diff(1) for details).
```